# Hide div when user clicks on the page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have created one div which has list of checkboxes and a button. This div is not shown when the page is loaded (style="display:none;" is set). This div should be shown only when user clicks on a particular image. Once the div is shown, if user clicks elsewhere on the page the div should be hidden.

How this can be achieved using Javascript?

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $(function(){   
    $("img").click(function(){
       $("div").show();
    });

    $(this).click(function(){
       $("div").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: _"if the user clicks **elsewhere** on the page, the div should be hidden."_. This will also hide the div if the user clicks on the div.

Comment: add a class to body tag "mycontainer" then replace this with "mycontainer"